# Spark Scala: How to save a grouped Dataframe to different files?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by

I have a data frame with a string column: `day` and other columns.
I want to do something like this:

`my_df.groupBy("day").writeEachGroup.option("header","true").csv("[dayofthegroup].csv")`

The dataframe `my_df` contains data for the month of January, I would like to get 31 different CSVs containing the data of each day, and give the name of the day to these files.

I am using spark 2.1 and Scala 2.11.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> give the name of the day to these files

It is impossible to give custom names to the output files, but you could rename them afterward.

> I would like to get 31 different CSVs containing the data of each day

If it's not mandatory to have strictly one file per day you might use `partitionBy` method

```
val df = Seq(
      (1, "data1"),
      (1, "data1_1"),
      (2, "data2_1"),
      (3, "data3_1"),
      (4, "data4_1"),
      (4, "data4_2"),
      (4, "data4_3")
    ).toDF("day", "data")

df.write.option("header", true)
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .partitionBy("day")
  .csv("report")
```

Output:

```
day=1/
  - file1
  - file2
  -...

day=2/
  - file1
  - file2
  -...
```