# pyspark delta table: How to save a grouped Dataframe to Different Tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006110/spark-scala-how-to-save-a-grouped-dataframe-to-different-files). How can I do same to write different groups of dataframe to different `delta` live tables? something similar to following where I am not limited by just panda dataframe. Allowing `apply` to pass either spark dataframe or a spark session to aggregate function.

```
def mycustomNotPandaAgg(key, Iterator, sparkSession|sparkDataframe):
   temp_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(Iterator) #I can apply schema here
   temp_df.createOrReplaceTable("temp_df")
   sparkSession.sql('insert into ... key as select * from temp_df') #key is table_name
   or
   sparkDataframe.writeToTable(key)  #where sparkDataframe is created internally from each group and passed into this apply function

my_df.groupBy("table_name").apply(mycustomNotPandaAgg)
```

ps - I have already tried `filter` approach where I filter same dataframe for each table, get N dataframe (1 for each table) and save them. It's not efficient as data is skewed per key. even if I `persist` the dataframe before `filter` spark still launches jobs for each filters.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this without pulling all data to the driver is by collecting the distinct keys, then writing each filtered DataFrame individually:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

filters = rtd.select("CustomerID").distinct().collect()
for f in filters:
    rtd.filter(col("CustomerID") == f[0]).show() # Replace show() with your write logic.
```

Note that unfortunately you will have to write the output tables serially. Could work around this with multiprocessing, or perhaps there is another commenter with a more Spark-native way to write groupBy results while using Spark for parallelization.

Comment: I had already tried this and it;s not efficient as data is skewed per key. even if I cache the dataframe before filter spark launches jobs for each filters.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could use the [partitionBy feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685695/6589230) to write Parquet as an intermediary, then write a short snippet to load the partitioned directories into your table?