# How to store dataset to jdbc simultatiously to different tables?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, concurrency

We have dataset with column named "table" to save to jdbc depend on table value.

We should filter by table and each result store to own table.

```
final Dataset<Row> dust = (create dataset).cache();

    final List<Object> tables = dust.select("table")
        .collectAsList()
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.getAs("table"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    tables.forEach(table -> {
        final Dataset<Row> tableDs = dust.filter(col("table").equalTo(table)).drop(col("table"));
        tableDs.write()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option(URL, etlConfig.getUrl() + "?currentSchema=" + schema)
            .option(USER, etlConfig.getUserName())
            .option(PASSWORD, etlConfig.getPassword())
            .option(DRIVER, ORG_POSTGRESQL_DRIVER)
            .option(DB_TABLE, tableName)
            .mode(APPEND)
            .save();
    });
```

1. How do we replace `tables.forEach` to repartition by column "table" to save into different tables simultaneously?

   Each time of `tables.forEach`, we wait for "write" operation.
2. I don't want to use Java concurrency features like `ExecutorService` or others. Because I want to remove `...cache();` and perform changes through one pipe (create dataset => filter by table => save to jdbc). All save to tables start simultaneously (not one by one)

I soe [Spark Scala: How to save a grouped Dataframe to different files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006110/spark-scala-how-to-save-a-grouped-dataframe-to-different-files)

in this case we cannot save to jdbc because need set  .option(DB_TABLE, tableName) But idea with partitionBy is quite good!